# The page is not redirecting properly by interceptor in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-interceptors, interceptorstack, struts2-rest-plugin

That's it, I code an interceptor login, the result is

```xml
<result name="login" type="redirectAction">access</result>
```

All works ok, but I think that is recalling it, the result go to access and again execute the interceptor and go access etc. I believe that because my browser shows the message:

> the page is not redirecting properly.

I'm using Struts 2 and Rest plugin.

**This is my interceptor:**

```
@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {

    HttpSession session = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession(false);
    Object loginObject = session.getAttribute("login");
    boolean login = false;

    if (loginObject != null) {
        login = (Boolean) loginObject;
        if (!login) {
            return Action.LOGIN;
        } else {
            return invocation.invoke();
        }
    } else {
        return Action.LOGIN;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I got it. I add `@InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack"`  _to exclude the execution of your Login Interceptor for the access_ Thanks Andrea.

Comment: glad that helped. Please note that on StackOverflow you don't need to edit your question's title to add SOLVED, instead you need to MARK the right question as ACCEPTED, and eventually to UP-VOTE every question that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return Action.LOGIN from within the Interceptor, the result is executed, and since the result is of type `redirectAction`, another request is created and filtered through the Interceptor Stack. Then the execution will trigger again your Interceptor, that is the unwanted result.

You need to exclude the execution of your Login Interceptor for the `access` action, using the default stack, for example.

```xml
<default-interceptor-ref name="myCustomLoginStack"/>

<action name="access" class="foo.bar.actions.Access">
    <result>access.jsp</result>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
</action>

<action name="foobar" class="foo.bar.actions.Foobar">
    <result>foo.jsp</result>
    <result name="login" type="redirectAction">access</result>
</action>
```

Comment: @SerchRac There's a mechanism on SO to indicate correct, useful answers--please äċċëṗẗ this answer if it fulfills your requirements.

Comment: Ha, a way around the comment filter :D

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Roman's remark re: setting session values to `true` and why it's superfluous:

Rather than check for the value of the session value, just check for its presence. On logout remove the session object, either explicitly (if you need other session data to remain) or invalidate the session.

This has the added benefit of reducing your code to approximately this:

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    Map    session     = invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession()
    Object loginObject = session.getAttribute("login");

    if (loginObject == null) {
      return LOGIN;
    }

    return invocation.invoke();
}
```

Regarding `getSession(false)`, it's generally unnecessary to include the boolean argument, since JSP pages will create sessions automatically unless explicitly declared not to.

Comment: Well, related enough I'd say :)

Comment: it's not a comment, but an answer, just forgot to add a link to the code with login interceptor.

Comment: @RomanC By "comment" I'm specifically referring to the last bit of the first sentence, to wit: "[...] which is superfluous". I'm explaining why it's superfluous. Even when I *agree* with you...?!

Comment: @DaveNewton I understand that you did it with good intentions, but on SO a comment is placed in the special section under post like this, and I didn't write a comment to OP's question.

Comment: @RomanC A "comment" can also be a "remark" contained within a larger context. Updated content.

Comment: you can use SO edit features to mark it as a comment if it's your comment not mine. Anyway I liked that +1

Answer (score 1):

Neither `login` or `access` is setting the `loginObject` to the session, nor they set it to `true`, which is superfluous. As a result, if you configured this interceptor to the action, it will prevent the action invocation and execution.

Comment: Yes, understood. Thanks.